# How to make a UIButton open up a SideView

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am making an app that has multiple view controllers that has a side view that you can go to navigate to each one, etc. I have everything set up and you can navigate to the side view by swiping from left to right to `revealViewController`, and that works splendid; however, what I would also like as well is to have a button that looks like 3 rectangles (not important to this, as I already designed the button) like on most apps, that you click and it would take you to that side view as if you where swiping like I have it set up right now. Does anyone know how to do this? I know it's pretty easy, but I am not quite sure.

An example of what I am trying to do, is in the Chase Mobile App. Even though this is a function that is in MANY different apps.
   [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IvCR.png]

This is EXACTLY what I am trying to do in the example/image above

All help is gladly appreciated!!

I need to have that button open up the side menu just like this. Right now I have it were you slide from one side to the other to get this. [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcIu2.jpg]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was from each tableView cell, instead of connecting it straight to the view I want it to show when you click that table cell, I had it go to a navigationaController with a segue (reveal view controller push controller) and then from that NavigationController I connected it to the view that I wanted it to display and connected it to that view controller by having a segue (root view controller), and then having the button in each view, and in each of the files .swift for those view controllers I connected the button up as you normally would, and for the code inside of the ViewDidLoad I have "menuBars.target = self.revealViewController()" and "menuBars.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))"

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code to toggle the sideview appear and disappear as :

```
[self.revealViewController revealToggleAnimated:YES];
```

and

```
 -(void)backButtonPressed {
    [self.revealViewController rightRevealToggleAnimated:YES];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called a hamburger menu (or sidebar menu) and is typically frowned upon for iOS design. There are a number of reasons for this, but they are still used in many applications. Basically, they hide links and information from the user that should be quickly accessible.

Disney recently recreated the navigation in their Disney World app. Previously they used this method to navigate the app, but they changed it up pretty well. I personally like the change and that they were able to fit a large amount of information and features into their app without a sidebar.

[image: Disney World App]

While I don't recommend using this design, it is a great method to learn if only to better understand making custom views. There are many tutorials that will help you set this up online. A good example is at [Appcoda](http://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/).

Basically, you will need a root view controller with two views in it: the menu and the content. You will switch the content view controller with the view that is selected and active in the menu. You can show and hide the menu a number of ways, but one of the easiest is to move the menu left or right to place it in the frame or out of the frame. The tutorial linked above will get you pretty far. I would have gone into more detail, but there are so many resources regarding this that I don't see the point in copy/pasting it here.

Comment: I already have this whole menu/function set up. The only thing I need is how to use the button to open the side menu up, at the moment you can slide it open with your finger. There are multiple reasons why I need to have this function, for if I use the model you show me, my app would look horrible, but thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Your app would only look horrible if you made it look horrible, design is not static...also, the tutorial I sent you should cover what you're asking

Comment: Very true! When I set this up just like in the tutorial it doesn't work. I am not sure what to do, since I have 6 different view controllers. and when I do this, it gives me an error saying for the first line of code " menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()"  I get the error "Cannot assign to property: 'target' is a method". And for the second line of code "menuButton.action = "revealToggle:" " I get the error message "Cannot sign to property : 'action' is a method" I am not quite sure what's wrong?

Comment: Those are not properties that you can set like that. To set a target you should use: ```button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(functionToRun), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)``` I would quickly look up selectors for Swift as well as selectors for buttons as they are not simply a normal function.

Comment: Note that it is possible to add multiple targets to one button, and each target will have a target and action. The target is usually `self` if you aren't sure

Comment: But what I put is what the tutorial told me to write, and when I watched this video on YouTube which helped me set up the whole thing that works right now, just not the button, I get the same message, and that's with using a selector like this "menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:)) "

Comment: Don't knock it until you try it! But for real, `addTarget(...)` is the appropriate way to do it through code and should work for you. Just make sure to take out that `menuButton.action = ...` part

Comment: Tutorials are not always 100% on, but I've found that raywenderlich tends to be a great resource

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I will try it this way a little later when I have access to my project. And I will come back and let you know what happened.